# JQuery - Change table cell embedded class dependent on content

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've currently got a HTML table pulling data from an SQL Server database. The page is built on Bootstrap 3.

The cell I'm interested in is:

```
<td><small class="label label-green"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>  <?php echo $result["t_owner"];?></small></td>
```

This returns the owner from the database and puts a bootstrap label around it.

label-green is the class I'd be changing dependent on the content. Essentially allowing me to assign a background color per User.

I've looked around but I can see how to change the class of an element inside the table cell based on the content.

Thank you in advance.